# How to find exr file is scan line or tiled image?

Tags: image-processing, compression, file-format, openexr

I have an exr file. I want to know if it is scan line or tiled. Is there any openexr api for finding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this api to check if file is tiled:
bool isOpenExrFile (const char fileName[], bool &isTiled);

Reference: see page 36
http://openexr.com/ReadingAndWritingImageFiles.pdf